# Dolphin 'Delete' option greyed out for folder

Tags: 22.04, delete, dolphin

Running Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 and the dolphin file browser won't let me delete a folder from one of my HDDs.

It's a "RECYCLE BIN" folder from having used it on windows, currently sitting at ~160GB so I'd really like to clear it out but neither right-click nor the delete key do anything and the 'delete' option in the menu is greyed out.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are a few things that could be stopping this. If the folder is not owned by you you cannot delete it without becoming the owner or using elevated privileges. You may be able to delete by using the following command in a terminal. `sudo rmdir “/path/to/folder/RECYCLE BIN”` Obviously you have to substitute the path to the folder and the correct name of the folder.

Comment: When I go to properties it show my username under the 'Ownership' area, I'll try that command and report back!

Comment: Within properties, the location is listed as "/media/(user)/Silver 2TB" but when I paste that into terminal after 'rmdir' it says "rmdir: failed to remove '/media/(user)/Silver': No such file or directory.

Comment: Your path is wrong. A space followed by 2TB is part of the path. Try `sudo rmdir “/media/(user)/Silver 2TB/RECYCLE BIN”`

Comment: The answer to this question may be relevant https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525624/how-to-fix-my-storage-drive-to-make-it-writable

Comment: Just got around to trying your last method of adding RECYCLE BIN, but in doing so I noticed that it's actually "$RECYCLE.BIN"... I can't help but wonder if the $ or the .BIN are the reason it's a problem

Comment: It was an external drive from the get go so I think the only remnants of Windows is this "folder". It is formatted in NTFS though but I'm not in a position to reformat at the moment. I'm hoping that isn't the only option. How is Linux with NTFS file systems in general? This is the only problem I've ran into so far but I've also just begun...

Comment: If it’s actually called $RECYCLE.BIN that’s what you use in the final part of the command. Linux commands will try to do exactly what you specify. They won’t do something similar just because it’s what you want. There is a space in your path between the silver and the 2TB. Because of that you need “ “ enclosing the entire path but not the rest of the command

Comment: If you are not going to use Windows with this drive it would be better to reformat it to a Linux filesystem. I’d suggest ext4, it’s rock solid. You can use NTFS for data storage in Linux (if dual booting) but there are some issues. You should have an app called GParted installed. It’s much like Windows Disk Management to use. Use that to reformat when you are ready.

Comment: Copy that! I just need to find a temporary home for ~1.6TB lol

Comment: If the data is important to you then you should keep a permanent backup:)